# Number of minimal sections in a (geometrically) ruled surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{P}(X)$ be a **non-trivial** $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over a curve $C$ (here $X$ is a vector bundle of rank 2 over $C$). A minimal section of $\mathbb{P}(X)$ is a section of minimal self-intersection.

My questions are the following:

1. Can $\mathbb{P}(X)$ admit a infinite number of minimal section? If not, why?
2. Is there a known example of non trivial $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle with $3$ distinct minimal sections (or infinite number of minimal section, and it would also answer my first question)?

The related examples that I know are the following:

- If $\mathbb{P}(X)\simeq \mathbb{F}_n$ is a Hirzebruch surface (i.e $C\simeq \mathbb{P}^1$) with $n\neq 0$. Then there exists an unique minimal section of self-intersection $-n$.
- If $C$ is an elliptic curve. It follows from the article (plus a little extra work): 
  *Maruyama, M.*, [**On automorphism groups of ruled surfaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/kjm/1250523688), J. Math. Kyoto Univ. 11, 89-112 (1971). [ZBL0213.47803](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0213.47803).,
  that all $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundles over $C$ have at most $2$ minimal sections.

Actually Maruyama shows for all curve $C$, independently of the genus, that if the minimal self-intersection is negative then the minimal section is unique. In particular, if the example I am looking for exists, then it should be over a curve of genus $\geq2$ and the minimal self-intersection is non-negative. Unfortunately, I don't know anything on vector bundles of rank $2$ over a curve of genus $\geq 2$ and I have not found any concrete examples ...

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Take a look on Maruyama's book on the classification of ruled surfaces.  I believe that such an example exists but the curve and the bundle will be very special.

Comment: A stupid example is $C \times \mathbb{P}^1$, where infinitely many minimal sections exist.

Comment: Indeed there are examples is in the end of the book of Maruyama, and my claim on the fact that the number of minimal section is at most 2 for a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over an elliptic curve is false. Thanks!

Comment: @Sasha Yes and I did not want this example. This is what I mean by "non-trivial"